# Android RecyclerView find bottom most child at position (x, y)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

In my Activity, I have a RecyclerView, with ItemTouchHelper attached to it. ItemTouchHelper, has overriden methods:

```
  @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        final int swipeFlags = 0;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
```

so, Views in RecyclerView are draggable;

My aim is to be able to drag one of the RecyclerView items through recyclerView and get View, that is under dragged view. So, I've tried to use [RecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(float x, float y)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findChildViewUnder(float,%20float)) which says: "Find the topmost view under the given point".

```
 @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        if (this.mRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(viewHolder.itemView.getX(), viewHolder.itemView.getY()) != null) {
            System.out.println(this.mRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(viewHolder.itemView.getX(), viewHolder.itemView.getY()).getTag());
            System.out.println(viewHolder.itemView.getX() + " " +viewHolder.itemView.getY());
        }

      //  mRecyclerView.
    }
```

But something weird is going on there.

When I drag certain item to the bottom of its original position (like in Image1), as you can see, findChildViewUnder() returns View that is under that dragged view (which is my aim).

[image: Image1]

But, if I drag item upper to its original position (like in Image2), than findChildViewUnder() returns dragged view (but not view under it).

[image: Image2]

Any suggestions? How can I always get a View that is under dragged item?